# Rails Devise find user by authentication token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm trying to do this:

class NotesController < ApplicationController

def index

@user = **User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:token])**

@notes = @user.notes

...

But I'm getting an error:

```
Started POST "/api/login" for 10.0.0.4 at 2013-07-22 13:20:43 +0300
Processing by Api::LoginController#login as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"pp@pp.pp"}, "login"=>{"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"pp@pp.pp"}}}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'pp@pp.pp' LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = 'GFRWkkLCq3xQx5rTRTFp' LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 119ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)


Started GET "/notes?token=GFRWkkLCq3xQx5rTRTFp" for 10.0.0.4 at 2013-07-22 13:20:44 +0300
Processing by NotesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"token"=>"GFRWkkLCq3xQx5rTRTFp", "note"=>{}}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = 'GFRWkkLCq3xQx5rTRTFp' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `notes' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/notes_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

As you can see, the code

```
User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:token])
```

Keeps returning nil.

Comment: Your error is `undefined method `notes' for nil:NilClass` 
means you are getting a nil user

Comment: I know. The question is why? As you can see I'm sending the token that I just got a second ago..

Comment: run the same sql in your db or run in rails console. If u are getting a valid user record?

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting nil from the console. That means that Devise dosn't saves the token for some reason..

Comment: how is your User model looks like?

Comment: and why so difficult? whay not just use `current_user` helper?

Comment: because i'm using a custom API for mobile app. There is no session control - just token.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:
The problem was that I forgot to save (commit) the user after the method **user.ensure_authentication_token**

```
def login
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(:email => params[:user][:email])
    if user.nil?
      render :json => {:result => 'ERROR'}
    else
      if user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
        user.ensure_authentication_token
        user.save
        render :json => {:result => user.authentication_token}
```